# measuring a test light's current draw?

Tags: current-measurement

I have a test light that has two wires, one connects to B+ and one to ground. You touch the test light on a component and the test light LED shines red if it finds power and green if it finds ground. I want to find the current draw of this light so I connected an ammeter in series: ammeter red lead connected to tip of light and then I touched the other lead to battery ground or positive. But I'm not getting a reading, even on the microamp scale. What could be the cause of this? This test light is unusual in that it connects to both batt posts, could that be an issue? I guess you could say it's connected in parallel to the battery.
Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It proably has a FET input and only draws nanoamps. 
connect a good clean ceramic capacitor to 5V on one lead. probe the other lead and see how long it takes for enough current to flow to extinguish the LED.

use the probe with a potentiometer and voltmeter to find this same voltage.

you can then compute how much current flowed in the capacitor.